# warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1. Add '+' to parent make rule

Tags: makefile

Here is my Makefile:

```
.PHONY: test%

test1:
    # jobserver is UNavailable
    make -C sub

test2:
    # jobserver is available, ok
    +make -C sub

test3:
    # jobserver is available, ok
    $(MAKE) -C sub

test4:
    # jobserver is available, ok
    +$(MAKE) -C sub
```

`sub` is sub-directory that contains another Makefile (sub-make).

When I run `test1` rule:

```
$ make -j8 test1
make -C sub
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
```

I get warning that jobserver is unavailable and `sub/Makefile` is really run in single thread (as if `-j1`).

They say I should add `+` and so I run a `test2` target which contains `+` before `make` command. And now I don't see the warning and `sub/Makefile` is really run in parallel. But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477400/5447906), the `+` sign is not for running in parallel but for forcing running commands even if `make` is run with `-n`, `-t`, `-q` flags. But why does `+` enables jobserver?

When I run `test3` target that doesn't use `+` but uses `$(MAKE)` for running `sub/Makefile`, it doesn't give jobserver warning as well (parallel execution works). So what is difference between `make` and `$(MAKE)`? I thought it is just for allowing to substitute default *make* with user-defined *make*. When I don't override `MAKE` variable, I see the same `make` command as I see in the `test1` target. But why does the `$(MAKE)` enables jobserver and `make` does not?

Running `test4` target does not give jobserver warning also (works in parallel).

Please note my question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53396967/5447906). It is about *cmake*, my question is about *make*. There is also [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9147196/5447906), but it doesn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The GNU make manual have decent [explanation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html) for this error. The point is: 'make' won't pass information about jobserver to the called process unless it is sure that called process is 'make' too.

> ‘warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1. Add `+' to parent make
>   rule.’
>
> In order for make processes to communicate, the parent will pass
>   information to the child. Since this could result in problems if the
>   child process isn’t actually a make, the parent will only do this if
>   it thinks the child is a make. The parent uses the normal algorithms
>   to determine this (see [How the MAKE Variable Works](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html#MAKE-Variable)). If the makefile
>   is constructed such that the parent doesn’t know the child is a make
>   process, then the child will receive only part of the information
>   necessary. In this case, the child will generate this warning message
>   and proceed with its build in a sequential manner.

Section [How the MAKE Variable Works](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html#MAKE-Variable) referenced in error description specifies two ways of telling 'make' that the invoked process is another instance of 'make': using `$(MAKE)` or `+`.
It states that:

1. One should use `$(MAKE)` variable when calling 'make' in the recipe.

   > Recursive make commands should always use the variable MAKE, not the
   >   explicit command name ‘make’, as shown here:
   >
   > ```
   > subsystem:
   >         cd subdir && $(MAKE)
   > ```
2. Using `$(MAKE)` and placing a `+` before the line that invokes 'make' in the recipe have same effect.

   > Using the MAKE variable has the same effect as using a ‘+’ character at the beginning of the recipe line.
3. Magic happens only if you explicitly type `MAKE` in the recipe. If this is not the case, use `+`.

   > This special feature is only enabled if the MAKE variable appears directly in the recipe: it does not apply if the MAKE variable is referenced through expansion of another variable. In the latter case you must use the ‘+’ token to get these special effects.

Comment: Thank you. In my case it helped, because I was wrapping a Makefile within a cmake target whose project was meant to user Ninja as make backend.